# Reorder Javascript object that contains special character

Tags: javascript, object

I'm reordering a javascript Object :

```
temp = [
  {one: 169, two: "0,1 - 6 m", three: "2", four: 12433},
  {one: 169, two: "> 9 m", three: "2", four: 12435},
  {one: 169, two: "0 - 0,1 m", three: "2", four: 12432},
  {one: 169, two: "6,1 - 9 m", three: "2", four: 12434}
];
```

I want to display two in an ordered dropdown select. I'm using this line to order correctly:

```
temp = temp.sort(
  function(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a.two.split(" - ")[0]) - parseInt(b.two.split(" - ")[0]);
  }
);
```

but I still have a problem with special characters '>' and '<'.

How can I replace those lines with '<' or '>' at the end of my JS Object?

Thank you

Comment: Which numbers in the `two` keys are you actually trying to exact? Not all contain `-`.

Comment: What output are you expecting ? I am unable to get your question clearly.

Comment: What about those properties without a `-`? The split would return the full string. I hope that’s not where you’re having a problem

Answer (score 0):

You could just split the strings and normalize them to get a number.

If the values are equal of start and end take either `1` or `-1`. Otherwise sort by the first value.

```js
const
    normalize = s => +s.match(/\d+(\,\d*)?/)[0].replace(',', '.'),
    temp = [{ one: 169, two: "0,1 - 6 m", three: "2", four: 12433 }, { one: 169, two: "> 9 m", three: "2", four: 12435 }, { one: 169, two: "0 - 0,1 m", three: "2", four: 12432 }, { one: 169, two: "6,1 - 9 m", three: "2", four: 12434 }];

temp.sort((a, b) => {
    const
        aa = a.two.split(' - ').map(normalize),
        bb = b.two.split(' - ').map(normalize);

    if (aa[0] === bb[1]) return 1;
    if (aa[1] === bb[0]) return -1;
    return aa[0] - bb[0]
});

console.log(temp);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```